# Crash on QString assignment

Tags: c++, qt

I'm pretty new to Qt and C++ so I'm probably missing something obvious, but for the life of me I can't figure out what is going wrong.  One of the classes in a program I wrote is causing a crash whenever I try to do a basic string assignment.  See below (slightly pared down).

```
class AutochargeData : public QWidget
{

public:
    AutochargeData(appData *appInfo, QWidget *parent = 0);

    QString orderNum;
    QString paymentMethod;
    QString total;

    void setPayment(QString payment);
    void setOrderID(QString orderID);
    void setTotal(QString total);

    void getPaymentData(QString orderID);

private:
    appData *appInfo;

};
```

So in the below code, I have tried many variations. I know the query is fine because I've used qDebug() to check the output.  I have tried skipping the set functions and doing a direct assignment, I have tried using the "this" keyword, and I have even tried just assigning a random string directly to the variables.

```
AutochargeData::AutochargeData(appData *appInfo, QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
    this->appInfo = appInfo;
}

void AutochargeData::getPaymentData(QString orderID)
{    
    QString queryString = "SELECT order_payment.method, order.increment_id, order.grand_total FROM order JOIN order_payment ON sales_flat_order.entity_id = order_payment.parent_id WHERE order.increment_id = '" + orderID + "';";

    QSqlQuery query(queryString, QSqlDatabase::database("db"));
    query.exec();

    while (query.next()) {
        setOrderID(query.value("increment_id").toString());
        setPayment(query.value("method").toString());
        setTotal(query.value("grand_total").toString());
    }
}

void AutochargeData::setPayment(QString payment)
{
    paymentMethod = payment;
}

void AutochargeData::setOrderID(QString orderID)
{
    orderNum = orderID;
}

void AutochargeData::setTotal(QString grandTotal)
{
    total = grandTotal;
}
```

Any time I tried to assign a string to the `orderNum`, `paymentMethod`, or `total` variables, the program crashes.  The debugger is ending on `QString::operator=(const char*)` in the `qstring.h` file.  As I mentioned, I am relatively new at this so it may be something obvious that I am missing.  But after multiple hours of googling and trying different variations, I am stumped.  Any thoughts would be much appreciated, and please let me know if there's more information that would be helpful.

Comment: What happens if you directly set a string instead of using the query data? like `setOrderID("hello")`

Comment: @rhodysurf crash. Even orderNum = "hello" causes a crash.  I've run clean and rebuild as well, still no dice.

Comment: IDK if this will matter but have you tried making your widget a `Q_OBJECT` by placing `Q_OBJECT` at the very top of the class declaration?

Comment: Are you mixing compilers here? Make sure that Qt was built with the same compiler and version that you are using for your application.

Comment: @rhodysurf Yes, it's actually there I just left it out in the post to simplify the code.  It shouldn't matter since I'm not using any signals/slots, but I do it as a default.

Comment: @drescherjm No mixing, the program works fine as long as I don't try to assign on of those three damn variables.

Comment: Perhaps `appInfo` is an invalid pointer. I assume it is dynamically allocated somewhere else in your program.

Comment: @drescherjm It isn't, I use it to great effect in other classes, and I also use it in this one to get the orderID for the SQL query (which runs fine, I have confirmed that it returns valid data)

Comment: You will probably have to debug some more. I do not believe you will find the answer from any other method.

Comment: @drescherjm any ideas on what I might try? I've spent the past couple hours debugging and I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: I do not believe the bug is in the code you posted. It is somewhere else in your code. You have corrupted the heap or one of your pointers causing this code to crash.

Comment: @drescherjm Okay, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As predicted, it was something obvious that I was missing.  I had created an instance of `AutochargeData` in the `Mainwindow` class, but was trying to use it in a different class without creating another instance of it.  So it was invalid, as was guessed in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

try to assign the query values to QString like this :

```
QString str=query.value(0).toString();

 setOrderID(str);
```